# R: loop through unique values of column and compute new variables

Tags: r, loops, unique

I am trying to iterate through a dataset by referencing the unique values in one column (SID). I want to create several variables based on existing columns in the dataframe. These will be computed for each unique value of SID. Currently, my code is not separating based on the unique value of SID. It is summing the values for the entire dataset.

Here is an example:

The data:

[fpd_2b.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnh5grlxolc859f/fpd_2b.csv?dl=0)

There are 40 rows in the dataframe. 20 rows have the value of "9003" in SID, and 20 have the value of "1028".

I want to create a variable and column called "numPR", which is the sum of the values of a column that already exists in the df ("PreviewRound"). The values in "PreviewRound" are 0s or 1s.

With this specific example, numPR should be 6 for each unique value of SID, however currently it is 12 (it is not separating by SID).

Here is the code:

```
file = "fpd_2b.csv"
headers = read.csv(file, header = F, nrows = 1, as.is = T)

df = read.csv(file, skip = 2, header = F)
colnames(df) = headers

# Remove blank rows (there is a blank row between each unique SID)
df = subset(df, SID  >1)

df$SID = factor(df$SID)

for (sid in unique(df$SID)) { 
  numPR = sum(df$PreviewRound)
  df$numPR = numPR
}
```

The entire column of numPR is filled with 12, however it should be filled with 6 (6 for 9003, and 6 for 1028). Any help would be much appreciated! I have checked out the similar posts on Stack Overflow and other sites, but haven't had luck with my issue. I'm sure the solution is quite simple, and many thanks for your assistance, folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to create a column, use 'SID' as grouping variable

```
df$numPR <- with(df, ave(PreviewRound, SID, FUN = sum))
```

or if we want a summarised output, use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(PreviewRound~ SID, df, FUN = sum)
```

---

The issue with the OP's code is how the values got replaced

```
df$numPR = numPR
```

in the OP's `for` loop and more importantly

```
numPR = sum(df$PreviewRound)
```

is taking the `sum` of the whole 'PreviewRound' column

The 'numPR' column is updated each time the `for` loop runs leaving only a single `sum` of the `last` updated `unique` 'SID'.  In order to avoid this, use an index

```
df$numPR <- NA
for (sid in unique(df$SID)) { 
    i <- df$SID == sid # create a logical index
    numPR = sum(df$PreviewRound[i]) # subet the data based on the index
  df$numPR[i] = numPR # assign the values only to those selected rows
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @akrun. I've put the other variables/columns that I wanted to create in the same loop and it's working like a charm. Many thanks for teaching me why it wasn't working as well instead of just providing the code.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. I've actually got another, very related question as well. I thought it was sufficiently different to warrant a different post, but wanted to shoot it your way as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951304/r-loop-through-unique-values-of-a-df-subset-and-update-df-with-new-variables